# Only allow checklist to be printed from button when all required boxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checklist for my customers to print. At the bottom is a button that allows them to print the checklist. How can I make it so that the checklist will not print unless all required checkboxes are checked?

Currently I have three text inputs the have to be filled out and will automatically check the first required box. But how do I lock down the print checklist button to check if the checkboxes are checked in order to let the user print from the button.

I know this doesnt stop the user from just cntrl "p"ing but if there is a way to completely stop them from doing that too I would be interested in that as well.

```js
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el) {
    // If the field is not empty....
    if (el.value !== "") {
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if (count === 3) {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true); // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Unheck the box
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headline">
  <h2>Checklist</h2>
</div>

<p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send in with paperwork.</strong></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" disabled /> Contact information
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown" /> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money" /> Check or money order
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" /> Application for Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82040</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" /> Identification document
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" /> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/poatip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title" /> Proof of ownership document
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.ownership")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership is "OOS Title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vinverification" id="vinverification" /> VIN Verification - <a href="forms/vinverification.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82042</span></a>
          <font color="red">*Required</font>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="billofsale" id="billofsale" /> Itemized dealer invoice, purchase order or Bill of Sale - <a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="leaseagreement" id="leaseagreement" /> Lease agreement
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="insuranceaffidavit" id="insuranceaffidavit" /> Florida Insurance card, policy, binder or Florida Insurance Affidavit - <a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 83330</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <!---<cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofinsurancetip.cfm">--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license is "Current">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="currentregistration" id="currentregistration" /> Proof of existing registration or license plate to transfer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency" /> Proof of Manatee County Residency document
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofresidencytip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form method="post">

  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print(); return false;" name="printpage" id="printpage"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</button>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"><strong class="icon-home"></strong> Finished</button>
  </div>
```

Any help or advice with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for easy identification, we add a 'required' class to the required checkboxes.

Second, to each of the required checkboxes, we add an event listener. When triggered, we'll check and update the the button's `disabled` property. Note, it's better to use the `input` event rather than the `blur` event.

I used js standard methods as I'm unfamiliar with jquery, but they seem mostly one-to-one translation.

```js
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el) {
    // If the field is not empty....
    if (el.value !== "") {
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if (count === 3) {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true); // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Unheck the box
  }
  
  checkCheckboxes();
});

let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];
let checkCheckboxes = () => document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled = checkboxes.some(check => !check.checked);
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('input',  checkCheckboxes));
checkCheckboxes();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headline">
  <h2>Checklist</h2>
</div>

<p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send in with paperwork.</strong></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required" disabled/> Contact information
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown"/> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money"/> Check or money order
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" class="required"/> Application for Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82040</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" class="required"/> Identification document
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa"/> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/poatip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title"/> Proof of ownership document
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.ownership")>
<cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership is "OOS Title">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vinverification" id="vinverification" class="required"/> VIN Verification - <a href="forms/vinverification.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82042</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</cfif>
</cfif>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="billofsale" id="billofsale"/> Itemized dealer invoice, purchase order or Bill of Sale - <a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="leaseagreement" id="leaseagreement" class="required"/> Lease agreement
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="insuranceaffidavit" id="insuranceaffidavit" class="required"/> Florida Insurance card, policy, binder or Florida Insurance Affidavit - <a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 83330</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <!---<cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofinsurancetip.cfm">--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license")>
<cfif session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license is "Current">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="currentregistration" id="currentregistration"/> Proof of existing registration or license plate to transfer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</cfif>
</cfif>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency"/> Proof of Manatee County Residency document
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofresidencytip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<form method="post">

  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print(); return false;" name="printpage" id="printpage"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</button>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"><strong class="icon-home"></strong> Finished</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: In your example the print button never lets you print

Comment: Could you clarify, it seems working for me. Checking the 5 required checkboxes  and the 3 required contact fields enabled the button. Clicking the button then opens the print dialog.

Comment: Its not enabling the button for me?

Comment: Im using google chrome and when I check the boxes with your snippet the button never becomes enabled

Comment: hmmm its spoty it just worked for me when I went straight down the line but then unwriting in the textboxes and it unchecking the first box did not deactivate it again

Comment: Is it possible to tie those three text boxes to it as well?

Comment: should i just put class required to those three boxes also

Comment: Also if I check the required boxes and then fill in the text boxes at the top to get that last checkbox checked it does not enable the print button. Its like it makes you do it from top to bottom or it does not work

Comment: You're right, it's because the 'input' event isn't fired when we set the 1st checkbox to true programmatically. I've updated it to call the `checkCheckboxes` function when setting the 1st checkbox.  But yes, you could merge the two checks together as well (and it would be cleaner that way).

Comment: would it be possible to have a warning message pop up when its disabled if the button is clicked saying all required checkboxes must be checked? Right now my button doesnt look disabled so people would just click it wondering why it doesnt work

Comment: `.disabled` "grays" out the button and is a pretty standard way to indicate visually a button is disabled. But sure, it's also possible to add a warning message, feel free to do so.

Comment: hmm maybe the way the css is set up its not showing any different. Yea I see yours is different. Interesting

Comment: Can you show me where to add the message in the code?

Comment: whenever you set `.disabled` to true or false, also set `warning.visible`.

Comment: I cant figure out how to add that warning. Can you assist by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022029/warning-if-required-inputs-are-not-selected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064816/adding-warning-when-button-is-disabled