# Warning if required inputs are not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a warning to `#printpage` when its disabled if its chosen saying please check required fields?

```js
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el) {
    // If the field is not empty....
    if (el.value !== "") {
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if (count === 3) {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true); // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Uncheck the box
  }

  checkCheckboxes();
});

let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];
let checkCheckboxes = () => document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled = checkboxes.some(check => !check.checked);
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('input',  checkCheckboxes));
checkCheckboxes();

$(document).on('click', '#printpage', function() {
  alert('clicked');
if ($("#printpage").is(":disabled")) {
   alert("Disabled");
 } else {
   alert("enabled");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headline">
  <h2>Checklist</h2>
</div>

<p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send in with paperwork.</strong></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required" disabled/> Contact information
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown" /> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money" /> Check or money order
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" class="required" /> Application for Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82040</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" class="required" /> Identification document
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" /> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/poatip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title" /> Proof of ownership document
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.ownership")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership is "OOS Title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vinverification" id="vinverification" class="required" /> VIN Verification - <a href="forms/vinverification.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82042</span></a>
          <font color="red">*Required</font>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="billofsale" id="billofsale" /> Itemized dealer invoice, purchase order or Bill of Sale - <a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="leaseagreement" id="leaseagreement" class="required" /> Lease agreement
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="insuranceaffidavit" id="insuranceaffidavit" class="required" /> Florida Insurance card, policy, binder or Florida Insurance Affidavit - <a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 83330</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <!---<cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofinsurancetip.cfm">--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license is "Current">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="currentregistration" id="currentregistration" /> Proof of existing registration or license plate to transfer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency" /> Proof of Manatee County Residency document
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofresidencytip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<form method="post">

  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print(); return false;" name="printpage" id="printpage"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</button>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"><strong class="icon-home"></strong> Finished</button>
  </div>
```

I have tried to add an onclick handler. The printpage button does not show the alert when the printpage button is clicked and disabled but it does show enabled once the button is enabled. If a button is disabled it will not send an alert?

Comment: please add HTML snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS function checkValidity(), this will return false if the form is not valid.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

```
isValid = $('.form').checkValidity()

if (!isValid) {
  $('#printpage').innerText = "Please fill in required fields";
  } else {
  $('#printpage').innerText = "";
}
```

Your html should contain HTML validity checkers, such as required.

```
<input required type="text" class="thisIsAClass" />
```

Comment: hmm for some reason this isnt working with my code. Can you show me how i can insert it into my already existing logic

Comment: with the JavaScript i posted above

Comment: Hey, before I code it in. Did you add a required attribute to your html? You can just put in the word required. Example: <input required type="text" />

Comment: if you look at ones like this it show <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required"

Comment: That only works when the HTML uses validation attributes.

Comment: @David class="required" is not the same as the attribute required. Here the attribute is "class"

Comment: I tried taking out class and putting just this: `<input type="checkbox" name="insuranceaffidavit" id="insuranceaffidavit" required />`