# Adding warning when button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```js
// Set up a blur event handler for each text field
$('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').on("blur", function(evt) {
  let count = 0; // Keep track of how many are filled in

  // Loop over all the text fields
  $('.form-control:not("#BusinessName")').each(function(idx, el) {
    // If the field is not empty....
    if (el.value !== "") {
      count++; // Increase the count
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  // Test to see if all 3 are filled in
  if (count === 3) {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", true); // Check the box
  } else {
    $("#contactinformation").prop("checked", false); // Uncheck the box
  }

  checkCheckboxes();
});

let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];
let checkCheckboxes = () => document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled = checkboxes.some(check => !check.checked);
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('input',  checkCheckboxes));
checkCheckboxes();

$(document).on('click', '#printpage', function() {
  alert('clicked');
if ($("#printpage").is(":disabled")) {
   alert("Disabled");
 } else {
   alert("enabled");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactName">Contact name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="BusinessName">Business name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="BusinessName" id="BusinessName" size="40" maxlength="120" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactEmail">Email address:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" size="40" maxlength="80" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactPhone">Phone number (business hours):</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone" size="40" maxlength="50" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="headline">
  <h2>Checklist</h2>
</div>

<p><strong>Check applicable boxes, print and send in with paperwork.</strong></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="contactinformation" id="contactinformation" class="required" disabled/> Contact information
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="feesbreakdown" id="feesbreakdown" /> Estimate of fees - <a href="forms/FeesBreakdown.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="money" id="money" /> Check or money order
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="certificatetitle" id="certificatetitle" class="required" /> Application for Certificate of Title - <a href="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82040</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofidentification" id="proofidentification" class="required" /> Identification document
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofidentificationtip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="poa" id="poa" /> Power of attorney document - <a href="forms/poa.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82053</span></a>
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/poatip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="title" id="title" /> Proof of ownership document
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.ownership")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.ownership is "OOS Title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vinverification" id="vinverification" class="required" /> VIN Verification - <a href="forms/vinverification.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 82042</span></a>
          <font color="red">*Required</font>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="billofsale" id="billofsale" /> Itemized dealer invoice, purchase order or Bill of Sale - <a href="forms/Billofsalevehicle.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="leaseagreement" id="leaseagreement" class="required" /> Lease agreement
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="insuranceaffidavit" id="insuranceaffidavit" class="required" /> Florida Insurance card, policy, binder or Florida Insurance Affidavit - <a href="forms/InsuranceAffidavit.cfm" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">Form HSMV 83330</span></a>
      <font color="red">*Required</font>
      <!---<cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofinsurancetip.cfm">--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<cfif isDefined( "session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license")>
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.transferring_vehicle_license is "Current">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="currentregistration" id="currentregistration" /> Proof of existing registration or license plate to transfer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="proofresidency" id="proofresidency" /> Proof of Manatee County Residency document
      <cfinclude template="../../../includes/proofresidencytip.cfm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      *For a list of all other forms not listed above that may be applicable - <a href="" target="_blank"><span class="noprint">(click here to print)</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<form method="post">

  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-orange" onclick="window.print(); return false;" name="printpage" id="printpage"><strong class="icon-printer"></strong> Print Checklist</button>
    <button class="btn-u" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"><strong class="icon-home"></strong> Finished</button>
  </div>
```

I am trying to add a warning message when `document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled` the printpage button is disabled to tell the user to check the required fields.

Where can I add the warning.visible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to add an onclick handler. The printpage button does not show the alert when the printpage button is clicked and disabled but it does show enabled once the button is enabled. If a button is disabled it will not send an alert?

Comment: Please add all the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Also, using destructuring syntax to turn a node list into an array so that you can call `.forEach()` successfully is incorrect. Any browser that doesn't support `.forEach()` on a node list is also not going to support destructuring. The correct way is: `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus its not letting me add the html i have put them here for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022029/warning-if-required-inputs-are-not-selected

Comment: If you just click to edit your question, you will then be able to add the HTML.

Comment: But, we need your HTML to be added to your question to be able to correctly answer it. That's why you were asked to add it in the other question you posted also. Always post ***all*** the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193106/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried to do something like this but I think I have the wrong idea completely. `if $("#printpage").is(":disabled") {
      alert("Disabled");
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got plenty of code here. It's always better to provide a minimal solution.
I tried to build a minimal solution for you.

I's CSS only, the Javascript is only for clarification on how it works.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

document.getElementById("toggle-disabled").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].toggleAttribute("disabled");
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-disabled-warning {
  display: none;
}

.btn[disabled] + .btn-disabled-warning {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn" disabled>My Button</button>
  <p class="btn-disabled-warning">The button is disabled :-(</p>
<div>
  
<div>
  <button class="btn">My Button</button>
  <p class="btn-disabled-warning">The button is disabled :-(</p>
<div>
  
<button id="toggle-disabled">Toggle disabled</button>
```