# creating alert when a button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I unable to create an alert when a button is disabled. But when the button is enabled I can get the alerts?

```
$(document).on('click', '#printpage', function() {
  alert('clicked');
if ($("#printpage").is(":disabled")) {
   alert("Disabled");
 } else {
   alert("enabled");
 }
});
```

Comment: Because the button is disabled.. ? And thus the click event isn't triggered.

Comment: This answer from another thread might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/924731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled button is not clickable.
If you want alert, use `class` instead of `disabled` attribute and stylize it with css.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#printpage', function() {
if ($("#printpage").is(".disabled")) {
   alert("Disabled");
 } else {
   alert("enabled");
 }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="disabled" id="printpage">Print</button>
```

Comment: "Disabling" a button using a class rather than the attribute doesn't provide the same effect - there might be a reason why the `disabled` attribute was used.

Comment: this is what I am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064816/adding-warning-when-button-is-disabled

Comment: @Adriani6, yes, you're right, but he wants the button to be clickable. I think, this is the only way to do this. Correct if I'm wrong

Comment: you can see my example above

Comment: thats the full picture. my complete goal is to be able to prompt the user to check all required fields when the button is clicked if all required fields are not already checked

Comment: is your class disabled the same as this disabled below?

Comment: `let checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox].required')];
let checkCheckboxes = () => document.querySelector('#printpage').disabled = checkboxes.some(check => !check.checked);
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('input',  checkCheckboxes));
checkCheckboxes();`

Comment: Actually no! You need to add `pointer-events: none` but with it too, it will not clickable

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina any chance you can look at my example here and show me what I can do to have an alert pop up when the button is disabled? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064816/adding-warning-when-button-is-disabled

Comment: You really want an alert when user clicks to disabled button?

Comment: I want to be able to pop something up saying please check all required fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193151/discussion-between-radonirina-maminiaina-and-david-brierton).

Answer (score 0):

You could also float an invisible element over the top of the button and put an onclick event on that. Obviously, you'd need to remove the element when you enabled the button. However, you'd always need to disable/enable the button through a function rather than simply setting the disabled attribute on the button itself.